# How to read a vector as CharacterVector in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

How can I read a `r` vector as a CharacterVector in `Rcpp`

I have a function

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('String readC(CharacterVector x) {
               for (int j=0; j < x.size(); j++)
                 Rcout << x[j] << std::endl;
               return "Yes";
 }')
```

Depending on the input it get converted to different type.

```
readC(c(TRUE,NA,1, 'Yes'))
$TRUE
$NA
$1
$Yes
readC(c(TRUE,NA,1))
$1
$NA
$1
readC(c(TRUE,NA))
$TRUE
$NA
```

How can I modify the function so that the expected output in the above cases are `TRUE, NA, 1, Yes`, `TRUE, NA, 1` and `TRUE, NA`.

Comment: `readC(as.character(...))`. Why are you passing non-character vectors like `c(TRUE,NA,1)` to a function expecting a character vector? Maybe you should be using a `Rcpp::List` instead of a `CharacterVector`.

Comment: In the `Rcpp` function I want them as converted character vectors. I do not want to modify the input but want a function that can take any input, convert them to characters. How should I use `Rcpp::List`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "so that it always read consistent input TRUE, NA ...". Please add the desired output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and realize that C(++) is typed.  So having a `CharacterVector` argument means ... all its components are character.  For which `NA`, but `TRUE` and `FALSE` are converted before you get them:

```
R> cppFunction('String readC(CharacterVector x) {
+                for (int j=0; j < x.size(); j++) print(x[j]);
+                return "Yes";
+             }')
R> readC(c(NA, Inf, -Inf, NaN, TRUE, FALSE, 42))
<CHARSXP: NA>
<CHARSXP: "Inf">
<CHARSXP: "-Inf">
<CHARSXP: "NaN">
<CHARSXP: "1">
<CHARSXP: "0">
<CHARSXP: "42">
[1] "Yes"
R>
```

Comment: `readC(c(TRUE, 0, 'Yes'))` returns 
`<CHARSXP: "TRUE"> <CHARSXP: "0"> <CHARSXP: "Yes">`. So `TRUE` and `FALSE` are not converted in all cases.

Comment: May depend on the ordering -- but all this is irrelevant. You want _custom_ formatting so you need to write yourself a custom formatting routine.